# How to get the last modified date and time of a microsoft planner task using Microsoft Graph APIs

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I referred [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannertaskdetails-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) documentation to try and get the **lastModifiedDateTime** of a planner task as in the JSON response example there is a property **"lastModifiedDateTime"**, however when I call the API endpoint "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/taskId/details" the response does not have that property.

Is there any other way I can get the lastModifiedDateTime property of a planner task?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Like said, currently not supported - there is an open feature request here you can upvote:
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/fe27394d-42d2-ec11-a7b6-000d3a54e061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last modified date time properties in the example are in the reference and checklist. Task currently does not expose as last modified date time property.

Comment: We're interested in how you'd use this property. Are you planning to do some kind of filtering, or plan this to be a user visible piece of information, or something else?

Comment: I am planning to use this property to update data at the backend by comparing the modification date time with what is there in the backend, as well as show the last modified date time to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the info. You can reliably use the ETag to detect if the data in the backend is different (for each entity, task and task details are different entities), if you store the ETag on the backend instead of the last modified date.

Comment: I didn't notice the difference in the Etag after every task update, so saving and updating the ETag after every change at the backend worked like a charm! Thanks :)

Comment: I made changes to some planner tasks and the ETag does not appear to change. does that only happen for certain types of changes??!!

Comment: This should be a different question. But etag will change for every change, but keep in mind task and task details have separate etags. Also changes that don't change the data are ignored, so the etag won't change for those.